# AMQPRuntimeException: Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 7 bytes

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

It was working, but now it's not working anymore!

I'm using php-amqplib and RabbitMQ.

[image]

when I'm  trying to create a new AMQP connection:

```
$connection = new AMQPConnection('localhost', 5672, 'username', 'password');
```

The code inside the library that is causing this error is:

```
public function read($n)
{
    $res = '';
    $read = 0;

    while ($read < $n && !feof($this->sock) &&
        (false !== ($buf = fread($this->sock, $n - $read)))) {

        if ($buf === '') {
            continue;
        }

        $read += strlen($buf);
        $res .= $buf;
    }

    if (strlen($res)!=$n) {
        throw new AMQPRuntimeException("Error reading data. Received " .
            strlen($res) . " instead of expected $n bytes");
    }

    return $res;
}
```

When I put this just before the exception:

```
die($res." :".$n);
```

the result is:

```
Ï :7 :7
```

it is called twice, in first call $res is two null characters then "Ï"

and in second call it's just null.

oh and I deleted files inside mnesia folder of rabbitmq database manually once, I don't know if that caused the problem, but the RabbitMQ Management which is a web based app running on port 15672 is working fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution.

the user I was using didn't have access to the vhost, so in RabbitMQ Management I went to the admin tab and clicked on the username, and clicked on "set permission" button.

Comment: Yes, this usually happens when you have the wrong credentials. I should update the lib and actually show a proper error message here.

Comment: yes, that would be better to show error message about credentials.

Comment: For our case we opened thousands of consumer connections  by mistake which exhaust the server and having the same error message

Answer (score 6):

You'll get this error also if port number is wrong. I was using management port 15672 instead of server port 5672 by mistake and was getting this same error.

So if user permission tweaking doesn't work then check connection parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has been answered already, but here's another possible cause:

The default "guest" user can only connect via localhost, by default.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html

I got this 'received 0' error when trying to connect remotely for the first time after testing successfully locally. Setting up a different user solved it for me.

```
rabbitmqctl add_user newuser <PASSWORD>
rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / newuser ".*" ".*" ".*"
```

This and many other potential answers are also on [github here](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/issues/72)