# EnvaySms : Getting error after i changed server PHP API

Tags: php

I have just changed my server  ( URL also changed ), earlier API worked fine but once i changed the server , it is not working . It gives me below error.
I opened the ports, removed firewall also.

```
PHP Warning:  fread(): Length parameter must be no more than 2147483647 in php-amqplib/amqp_wire.inc on line 304
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Error reading data. Recevived 0 instead of expected 4294779135 bytes' in php-amqplib/amqp_wire.inc:318
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May be this help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25226607/amqpruntimeexception-error-reading-data-received-0-instead-of-expected-7-bytes

Comment: Okay , Thanks @vijay , Will check and back to you on this.